# Acumatica - What is the best solution for updating a other order when the delete event is call?

Tags: events, event-handling, acumatica

The UpdateParentAllocation function have a graph for updating a other order. The acuminator mentioned : *A PXGraph cannot be created withnin an event handler*. I was thinking to override the delete event. Is it the best solution in Acumatica and how can I override a delete event?

```
       protected virtual void SOLine_RowDeleted(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e, PXRowDeleted del)
    {
        del?.Invoke(sender, e);

        var row = (SOLine)e.Row;
        var rowExt = row.GetExtension<SOLineDAExtension>();
        if (row == null || IsBlanketOrder)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        UpdateParentAllocation(rowExt, row.OrderQty.GetValueOrDefault() * -1);
    }
```

Here the UpdateParentAllocation function

```
    protected virtual void UpdateParentAllocation(SOLineDAExtension rowExt, decimal? newQtyBL)
    {
            var blOrder = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
            blOrder.Document.Current = blOrder.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderNbr>(rowExt.DABlanketOrderNbr, rowExt.DABlanketOrderType);
            blOrder.Transactions.Current = blOrder.Transactions.Search<SOLine.lineNbr>(rowExt.DABlanketLineNbr, rowExt.DABlanketOrderNbr, rowExt.DABlanketOrderType);

            if (blOrder.Document.Current == null || blOrder.Transactions.Current == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            blOrder.Transactions.Current.Qty = newQtyBL;
            blOrder.Transactions.Update(blOrder.Transactions.Current);
            blOrder.Actions.PressSave();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PXTrace.WriteError(ex.ToString());
            throw new PXException(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you need to do this via a different graph as in your sample code, try overriding Persist.  If you can do it safely within the current graph itself, then you can define a view in your graph extension and find/delete the record via the view in an event handler... but only if there isn't business logic defined in another graph that needs to be called.  In that case, we are back to preference of overriding persist.

Comment: @BrianStevens I already try to overriding persist but I don't have the value of the line deleted. I try with the PXSelect in the override Persist to get the line deleted but it return null.

Comment: Been there.  Understand.  Create a private variable for the graph.  Store the value you need in rowdeleted, and use it in persist.

Comment: Another thought.  If the record you want to delete is a "child" (always) of the record already being deleted, it will delete the child automatically if you include in your DAC the PXParent attribute and the proper relationship to the "parent".  I'd need to see a lot more code to understand what you are doing, but it almost looks like you are working in a graph extension of SOOrderEntry and trying to initialize the same graph to delete your record.  You could just create a view and delete your record from the view in a rowdeleted event of the other DAC.